# Why do I get these warnings from Kotlin generated code by Protobuf?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I created a ProtoBuf file "event.proto" and used the command

`protoc --java_out="$JAVA_MAIN_PATH" --kotlin_out="$KOTLIN_MAIN_PATH" event.proto`

with the paths I needed in my Kotlin project.

Then my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA community) showed the following warnings:

```
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/EventContextKt.kt: (13, 5) JvmField has no effect on a private property. This warning will become an error in further releases
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/EventContextKt.kt: (118, 5) Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/EventContextKt.kt: (134, 5) Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/EventKt.kt: (13, 5) JvmField has no effect on a private property. This warning will become an error in further releases
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/JourneyKt.kt: (13, 5) JvmField has no effect on a private property. This warning will become an error in further releases
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/UserKt.kt: (13, 5) JvmField has no effect on a private property. This warning will become an error in further releases
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/UserKt.kt: (87, 5) Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types
[WARNING] <...path>/protos/event/UserKt.kt: (103, 5) Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types
```

Other than that the code compiled successfully.

Is there a way to solve the issue so the warnings will be gone? Other than editing the ProtoBuf code manually, which is probably not the way to go.

Comment: It's probably worth adding version information. What versions of `protoc`, Kotlin, and IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: libprotoc 3.17.3

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-212.5284.40, built on September 14, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1024M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: idea.plugin.protoeditor (212.5080.8), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.5.31-release-546-IJ4638.7)
Kotlin: 212-1.5.31-release-546-IJ4638.7

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/8804. Make sure you're using the latest version of Protobuf.